# MATCH data with log events

Tags: sql, teradata

I have a table `events` which looks like this:

- check_date, Id

I have a table `contracts` which looks like this:

- sign_date, Id

I would like to get add a column (Boolean) to the `contracts` table with a query. The new column (`evaluated`) which is:

- `True` if there exists at least a row in `events` where the contract `Id` is matched and (`sign_date` - `check_date`) is between 0 and 3. We can have multiple events when a contract is check logged into `events`. I need to see if there is at least one that took place the same day of the contract signature or maximum 3 days earlier.

What would be the neatest way to do this? A left join and then a further `SELECT distinct` where we have a match seems a weird way to go.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, something like this:

```
SELECT t.sign_date,t.id,
       max(CASE WHEN s.id is null then 'false' else 'true' end) as boolCol
FROM contracts t
LEFT OUTER JOIN events s
 ON(t.id = s.id and sign_date - check_date between 0 and 3)
GROUP BY t.sign_date,t.id
```

Comment: yes, this is what I have in mind. I think there's no one shot way to go.

Comment: What? I didn't understand the question.. this is how you should do it @NoIdeaHowToFixThis

Answer (score 1):

You should compare Explains (and resource usage) for both versions,  `MAX` vs. `DISTINCT`:

```
SELECT DISTINCT c.*,
   (CASE WHEN e.id IS NULL THEN 'N' else 'Y' end) AS boolCol
FROM contracts AS c
LEFT OUTER JOIN events AS e
  ON c.id = e.id 
     -- I simplified your date logic
 AND c.sign_date BETWEEN e.check_date - 3 AND e.check_date)
```

`DISTINCT` is easier to write and the optimizer might automatically replace it with `GROUP BY` processing.